# Upgrade from Fedora 30 to 31: Cannot enable multiple streams for module 'ant'

Tags: fedora, dist-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from Fedora 30 to 31 and I've successfully done these two steps:

```
dnf upgrade --refresh
dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade
```

However, when I do the next:

```
dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=31
```

... I get this:

```
Before you continue ensure that your system is fully upgraded by running "dnf --refresh upgrade". Do you want to continue [y/N]: y
Adobe Systems Incorporated                      35 kB/s | 2.9 kB     00:00    
Fedora Modular 31 - x86_64                      23 kB/s |  25 kB     00:01    
Fedora Modular 31 - x86_64 - Updates            19 kB/s |  16 kB     00:00    
Fedora 31 - x86_64 - Updates                    17 kB/s |  18 kB     00:01    
Fedora 31 - x86_64                              37 kB/s |  25 kB     00:00    
google-chrome                                   18 kB/s | 1.3 kB     00:00    
MariaDB                                        9.7 kB/s | 2.9 kB     00:00    
packages-microsoft-com-prod                     16 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
PostgreSQL common RPMs for Fedora 31 - x86_64   11 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
PostgreSQL 12 for Fedora 31 - x86_64           3.3 kB/s | 3.8 kB     00:01    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 31 - Free - Updates       29 kB/s | 9.1 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 31 - Free                 26 kB/s | 9.9 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 31 - Nonfree - Updates    11 kB/s | 9.4 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 31 - Nonfree              21 kB/s |  10 kB     00:00    
skype (stable)                                 6.6 kB/s | 2.9 kB     00:00    
teams                                          4.9 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
Fedora 31 - x86_64 - VirtualBox                247  B/s | 181  B     00:00    
Visual Studio Code                              19 kB/s | 3.0 kB     00:00    
Yarn Repository                                 25 kB/s | 2.9 kB     00:00    
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'libdnf::ModulePackageContainer::EnableMultipleStreamsException'
  what():  Cannot enable multiple streams for module 'ant'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there some way to overcome this problem? Any and all ideas are welcome. I don't mind if I have to disable/remove some of my extra package repos, if that is what it takes ...

Comment: I even removed maven and ant from my system and it's still whining about it can't upgrade maven because of multiple streams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really weird but I have stumbled on this issue too and found out that you have to disable these repos:

- fedora-modular.repo
- fedora-updates-modular.repo
- fedora-updates-testing-modular.repo

Thanks @vonbrand and @dbdemon for the idea.

Comment: I disabled those, and a few other repos, which allowed the upgrade to progress. Half-way through I got a nasty error and was dropped out to the terminal with what looked like a broken upgrade. Fortunately, a reboot allowed the upgrade to continue and complete successfully.

Comment: When I  attempt to disable the repo I get the following ```sudo dnf --disable fedora-modular
--enable, --set-enabled and --disable, --set-disabled must be used with config-manager command.```

Comment: @FilBot3 Try `sudo dnf config-manager --disable fedora-modular`

Comment: I found that I also needed to only upgrade one version at a time in addition to disabling the modular repos.

Answer (score 20):

### Dummies guide to disabling modular repos

I wasn't sure exactly what this [comment from dbdemon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579184/upgrade-from-fedora-30-to-31-cannot-enable-multiple-streams-for-module-ant#comment1078151_579250) meant:

> It seems I had to disable the "Fedora Modular" repos.

So a bit of searching brings up this article on [How to use Fedora / RHEL 8 Modular Repository](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-use-fedora-29-modular-repository/).

You can list the modular repos that you have installed by:

```
dnf module list --enabled
```

I got this output:

```
Docker CE Stable - x86_64                        12 kB/s | 9.8 kB     00:00    
...
Fedora Modular 30 - x86_64
Name    Stream         Profiles    Summary                                      
gimp    2.10 [d][e]    default [d] GIMP                                         
                       , devel     
ripgrep latest [d][e]  default [d] Line oriented search tool using Rust's regex 
                                   library

Fedora Modular 30 - x86_64 - Updates
Name    Stream         Profiles    Summary                                      
fd-find rolling [d][e] default [d] Simple, fast and user-friendly alternative to
                                    find
gimp    2.10 [d][e]    default [d] GIMP                                         
                       , devel     
ripgrep latest [d][e]  default [d] Line oriented search tool using Rust's regex 
                                   library

Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled
```

Note: The bits at the end tell you which modules you have installed. However I'm pretty sure that I didn't *intentionally* install these modular repos, it just happens that some developers have enabled them. I just ran `sudo dnf install ripgrep` and it installed the modular repo.

So from this list I have, `fd-find`, `ripgrep` and `gimp` installed as modules.

I can then disable these for example for `ripgrep`:

```
sudo dnf module disable ripgrep
```

You just need to do the same for which ever modules you have listed.

Once I had disabled my 3 modules I could run the Fedora upgrade without problem:

```
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=31
```

Comment: Your instruction worked for me.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

According to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1811234, disabling the problematic modules works, but you'll want to remember to re-enable them after the upgrade.
A possibly simpler solution mentioned there is:

```
sudo dnf module reset '*'
```

Then during installation it'll say something like:

```
Enabling module streams:
 gimp                                          2.10                                                     
 maven                                         3.5                                                      
 meson                                         latest                                                   
 ninja                                         latest                                                   
 ripgrep                                       latest
```

I don't fully understand how it works, but from https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/modularity/using-modules-switching-streams/ it seems that a module can have at most 1 "stream" selected, and `reset` clears that selection allowing another stream to be chosen?

Comment: note the fix for bug 1811234 was released today.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a problem with any module like 'ant' or 'maven', and removing module doesn't work, try to reset the module with command:

"dnf module reset ", exmaple: dnf module reset maven

It worked for me with "maven" module, same error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'libdnf::ModulePackageContainer::EnableMultipleStreamsException'
  what():  Cannot enable multiple streams for module 'maven'

Comment: Worked for me with the gimp module too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform following steps:

**1)** As @icc97 said execute `dnf module list --enabled` command and get something like:

```
Fedora Modular 30 - x86_64 - Updates
Name                           Stream                               Profiles                                    Summary                                                                          
ant                            1.10 [d][e]                          default [d]                                 Java build tool                                                                  
fish                           3 [d][e]                             default [d]                                 Friendly interactive shell                                                       
gimp                           2.10 [d][e]                          default [d], devel                          GIMP                                                                             
maven                          3.5 [d][e]                           default [d]                                 Java project management and project comprehension tool
```

2. Then run `sudo dnf module reset gimp ant fish maven` (after `reset` part you are inputting only ones listed in results above).
3. Run `dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=31` command and wait for listing of packages to be displayed for installation and choose 'y(es)' and then...proceed normally with installation. :)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try only with the standard repositories, then add the others one by one. I'd start with the larger/more common ones first (RPM Fusion), the more niche ones are more probable to cause grief. Besides, why e.g. Postgres repository? What's wrong with the distribution's version? Check you *really* need all that non-distribution stuff.

Comment: That seems to have helped - the upgrade is now progressing. It seems I had to disable the "Fedora Modular" repos. And yes, I absolutely need all those repos because I need the latest and greatest of things that interest me, especially database systems :)